# Click on nav-element loads/includes new content/file.php into div id="include"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for the best (fast, does not need a lot of performance, easy to understand, et cetera) method of loading some content from a php-file into a div of my page.

I don't know if it's better to use php or javascript maybe? If javascript, I think there is no need for jquery, right?

The solution should  be 100% valid (w3c, jshint, et cetera).

On first page load: should some specific includes-file be loaded, or just nothing but the original content of my div should be shown?

There should be no reload of the whole page, just the div should be reloaded / the content of the div should be replaced when clicking on the navigation-link.

(It should not matter, what the files which are loaded/included are named so I don't want a solution which does only load files with the names file_1.php ... file_9.php.)

The files also just have plain html in it, like if I would write it directly into the div of my html-file.

The files which should be included are e.g. called about.php, contact.php, services.php…

My html/php file looks like this:

```
<html>
</html>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="imports/some_name.php">...</a></li>
        <li><a href="imports/something_else.php">...</a></li>
        <li><a href="imports/well_whatever.php">...</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="include">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to lead the content in div in my opinion is using jQuery. 
It will be compatible with major browsers, and simple to implement.

Actually I use this solution in one of mine apps

```
$(document).on('click', '#nav a', function(event) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax(url).done(function(response, status) {
        if (status !== "error")
        {
            $("#include").html(response);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Explaining:

$(document).on('**event**', '**filter**', **handler**) is a function that bind a **handler** function to every '**event**' filtered by '**filter**'.

(More info at [jQuery Documentation .on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/))

Inner the handler, I use a jQuery function called [.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), that receives a url as parameter (and some options if necessary), and call a callback function using defered.done().

This callback receives *response* data, *status* string and the *xhr* object as described in jQuery documentation. (In this case we do not use the xhr object, then we can remove it from function)

First I check if status is not a error. Then I select the '#include' element (jQuery uses a css like selector syntax), and use html function to put the response inner #include div.

For last, i use *event.preventDefault()* to avoid browser from trying to follow the link.

---

However, if you want to use pure JavaScript, you will need to handle different browsers behavior, and you will take a long time to get 100% compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Which jquery-version should you use for that? And could you please explain a little on how to work with your code? For others. And also for me, think I don't understand the $("#include").html part.

Is this code valid? JShint tells some warning, but maybe because of the missing jquery.

Comment: Thanks. Should I use latest jquery.min for this?

Comment: Sorry I don't get that to work. I created a js file with your code as content. I'm using jquery 1.11.0 also. And I'm using my structure from above. My <a>'s in <div id="nav" class="column third"> also have class="nav", but that shouldn't be the problem, right? — (By not working I mean: I just can say browser now follows the links…)

Comment: The files which should be included are e.g. called about.php, contact.php, services.php…

Comment: Console says: Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined include.js:2
(anonymous function) include.js:2
n.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
r.handle

Comment: Oh, and I removed ", xhr" also, as you said it's not needed.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to define who is *var url*.

I edited the code, also removede *xhr*, and added: **var url = $(this).attr('href');**

Comment: Thanks very much in advance! I can't upvote yet, so I have to say it this way.

Comment: You'r welcome. :) Check if it works perfectly.
jQuery is a very good (and easy) way to solve interface problems without caring about browser/browser version compatibility.

Comment: It seems to work perfectly! Though, I'm not able to test it in all browsers and on all mobile device-types yet. – Good to know this fact about jquery! Thanks again!